# Large JSON packet causing remote CFC to be unresponsive during ajax call

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfc, railo

I am doing an ajax post that submits a user's comment to a remote CFC via AJAX. The code works absolutely fine all of the time, EXCEPT when the comment character length gets to about 7300 characters. Then, it's as if the CFC just doesn't do anything.

In Firebug, I can see that for all comments submitted < 7300 characters, the response comes back just fine, however, for packets > 7300 characters, this response is blank.

So, naturally I added some simple logging into the remote cfc method being called. I removed all code and just did some simple logging, and even that did not execute as nothing was logged. Remove a few characters from the comment and resubmit and it works again.

So something is leading me to believe that for large packets sent that are > 7300 characters, the CFC is somehow rejecting the request. Is this possible? Could something be causing this? I have looked in the Administrator but don't see any settings related to this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Below is the code for the CFC. I found it unneccessary to submit any jquery / ajax javascript code as it definitely works and this issue is related to the size of the request, but if you feel it may help, let me know and I'll post it too.

CFC being called:

```
<cffunction name="callFunction" access="remote" returntype="any" output="false">
        <cfargument name="cfc" type="string" required="yes" hint="The path or alias for the cfc to call" />
        <cfargument name="functionName" type="string" required="yes" hint="The function name within the requested cfc to call" />
        <cfargument name="returnFormat" type="string" default="json" hint="The format of the repsonse: xml, json, wsdl, etc." />
        <cfargument name="jsonData" type="string" required="false" />
        <cfargument name="isLoginRequired" type="boolean" default="true" />
        <cfset application.Security.LogItem("CFC: #arguments.cfc#", false, false) />
        <cfset application.Security.LogItem(arguments.jsonData, false, false) />

        <cfset var sResponse = this.Utilities.GetNewResponse() />
        <cfreturn sResponse /></cffunction>
```

Comment: Are you calling via an HTTP GET or POST (i.e. URL or FORM)? Because GET is size limited in most browsers.

Comment: Thanks - that was exactly the problem. I use one gateway function for all AJAX requests and it was set to 'get' as the type. I changed it to 'post' and it worked. This led me to quickly look up the difference between the two and when to use each and I learnt another important lesson on how each is treated, which is quite important when spiders / bots are crawling the site. I'm not sure how I can mark your comment as the answer though? Do you want to just repost it as a reply? Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you calling via an HTTP GET or POST (i.e. URL or FORM)? Because GET is size limited in most browsers.